# data-toggle="collapse" within active data-toggle="tab" doesn't function

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a working tab pane setup in the lower left div here (content is loaded by clicking any of the EDUCATION/FAQ/REVIEWS buttons): http://dev.backcountryaccess.com/product/tracker-2/

My trouble is when trying to add a simple collapse function within the FAQ section, it refuses to function. I've tried adding just the most basic of examples straight from Bootstrap:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">simple collapsible</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse in">some text</div>
```

But no with no luck, the button loads, but there is no collapse functionality...

Comment: Can you provide a sample code and example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Hmmm, I went and created a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/davereed362205122/BGJg7/) and everything there seems to work just fine, so must be some intricacy within my site in particular... I'll keep digging and see if I can drudge up a solution.